# Why is $model returning an array instead of a model when using a Livewire trait?

Tags: php, laravel, hydration

I want to add a trait for using modals on my livewire components, that I can use them again without declaring some variables every time.

Now I'm a bit confused about hydrating and dehydrating of models in livewire.
Here is what I did:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Traits;


trait WithConfirmationModal
{
    public $showModal = false;
    public $model;

    public function showModal($model): void
    {
        $this->showModal = true;
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function closeModal(): void
    {
        $this->showModal = false;
        $this->model = null;
    }
}
?>
```

in $model I wanted to use the model
which is used in an Index:

```
use WithConfirmationModal;

public function deleteUser(DeleteUser $deleter)
{  
   $deleter->delete(Auth::user(), $this->model);
}
```

and in blade file:

```
<div wire:click="showModal({{ $user }})" class="inline cursor-pointer text-red-600 hover:text-red-900 ml-2">Delete</div>
```

I just want to store the user model in $model. Instead of this its saving me an array, that I cannot simply $model->delete();

If I define User in trait as User Model (public User $model) its working, but I want to use this in more Models as just as User. :-)

How can I solve this?

Greetings!

Comment: You'll have to abstract it... delete-functionality should be in an interface, which User (and other classes) have to implement, then pass the "DeletableInterface" object to the trait method (not the concrete class).